# ACCESS form expression builder

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to display a record from a table after the user enters the input. I have several tables but the one from which I am trying to take the data is called Tocki. Till now I came up with this expxression:

```
=DLookUp("[Tocki]![Y]"," [Tocki]![X]"," [Tocki]![H]";" [Tocki]![Broj]="&[Text3])
```

I want to display the columns Y, X and H from the table Tocki. My text field is called Text3 and I want to search the table through the column Broj.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean a textbox is named Text3?

Cannot pull 3 separate fields with DLookup, you can pull a concatenation of those three fields. If Broj is a text type field, filter parameter needs apostrophe delimiters.

`=DLookUp("[Y] & ':' & [X] & ':' & [H]", "Tocki", "[Broj]='" & [Text3] & "'")`

However, DLookup can be slow performer. Better approaches usually:

1. include lookup table in the form RecordSource, bind textboxes and set them Locked Yes and TabStop No
2. multi-column combobox, then textboxes can reference the combobox columns by index